# How do you produce/create tables in Geraldo Reports?

Tags: python, django, report, reportlab, geraldo

I am looking for a snippet of code that produces a simple table layout in geraldo reports. Can someone help please? I checked the docs but no additional info on the format.

Answer (score 0):

This code generates report using geraldo
[PySPED](https://github.com/odoo-brazil/PySPED/blob/8.0/pysped/nfe/danfe/danfepaisagem.py)

it looks like [Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7hHm.png)